# VSCODE - Marketplace returned 'ECONNREFUSED'. Please check the 'http.proxy' setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio. I just installed Visual Studio Code (VSCODE). First time, I opened it and trying to install the extension for powershell. But, when I go to the Extensions tab, it gave an error that the proxy settings were not configured.

The pop up gave an option to 'Open User Settings' and it opened an editor. 
As per my understanding, I wrote the following two lines in the User Settings file.

Our internal proxy server requires user authentication. How and where will I put the user credentials. I think, I am getting the error because I have not specified the user details.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Found out how.
The proxy details should be given in the following format. I was using the wrong format earlier.

My settings file looked something similar to below.

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
```

`{`
`"http.proxy": "http://user@domain.local:Password456@10.201.10.200:8080",`
`"http.proxyStrictSSL": false`
`}`

The domain user name was domain\user, and it was provided in the user FQDN format
Password456 is the login password for the user
10.201.10.200:8080 is the proxy server

Hope this would help someone at some point of time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem like @Tom Jacob Chirayil, but I had to do a little extra. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Find your proxy server first by going to http://wpad/wpad.dat. My company's configuration had a bunch of proxy servers, and the one that I used was at the very bottom, in this format:

   `return "PROXY subdomain.company.com:port";`
2. Then click on the `Open User Settings` button, and add the following line to the `settings.json` file to the right, within the braces:

   `"http.proxy": "http://subdomain.company.com:port"`

   NB: I had to add `http://` to the front of the proxy address that I pulled from `wpad.dat`.
3. Then save `settings.json`, restart VS Code. (IDK for sure if you have to restart VS Code or not.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a point, it seems that the new release (1.5.1) came with this issue. People on Mac, Linux or Windows suffering with "**econnrefused**" error in VSCode.

The new version (1.5.2) will have a fix for this, until then, we can use the *nightly* version.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11774

Comment: I am using 1.5.2 version. But still facing the same issue

Comment: @RamakrishnaYelduti you can upgrade to the newest version (as of today, 1.38.1) and try out, or maybe verify the proxy in the company or if it is the firewall. ;)